# Verification of proof involving a function and an equivalence relation

Tags: functions, solution-verification, relations

As part of my effort to learn how to write proofs I'm working on my own through How to Prove It by Daniel J. Velleman. I have some doubt about my answer for part (c) of exercise 13 in section 5.3 and wanted to see if my attempted solution is correct because other proposed solutions I have seen are not done the same as mine.

Before stating the question I will state what is given. Suppose $f$ is an onto function from some arbitrary set $A$ to some arbitrary set $B$. Let $R = \{(x,y) \in A \times A ~ |  ~ f(x) = f(y)\}$. We have proven in a previous exercise that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$. In part (a) of this exercise we have shown that there is a function $h:A/R \rightarrow B$ such that for all $x \in A$, $h([\,x]\,_{R}) = f(x)$. In part (b) of this exercise we have shown that $h$ is one-to-one and onto.

Now the question is: It follows from part (b) that $h^{-1}:B \rightarrow A/R$. Prove that for all $b \in B$, $h^{-1}(b) = \{x \in A | f(x) = b\}$.

My attempted solution:

Let $b$ be arbitrary and suppose $b \in B$. Since $f$ is onto then there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Then from our given, $f(a) = b = h([\,a]\,_{R})$ and since $([\,a]\,_{R}, b) \in h$, then $(b,[\,a]\,_{R}) \in h^{-1}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
h^{-1}(b) = [\,a]\,_{R} &= \{x \in A | a R x\} \\
 &= \{x \in A | f(a) = f(x)\} \\
 &= \{x \in A | f(x) = f(a) = b\} \\
 &= \{x \in A | f(x) = b\}
\end{align}

Since $b$ was arbitrary, this shows that for all $b \in B$,  $h^{-1}(b) = \{x \in A | f(x) = b\}$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @DanVelleman Okay, thank you for verifying.